# For Loop not working in custom javascript variable for Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, google-tag-manager

My website does not have a data layer and I am trying to scrape the DOM element to pass some data to a custom Javascript variable. I am a newbie to both HTML and Javascript and hence I seem to be making a mistake.

The For loop for multiple products is not working - I am getting an error - *"Error at line 17, character 16: Parse error. '{' expected"*

This is my code:

```
function() {
var a = document.querySelectorAll("p.product-name");
var b = document.querySelectorAll("small.cart_ref");
var c = document.querySelectorAll("input.cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey");
var d = document.querySelectorAll("li.price");
var ecommerceData = {
'ecommerce': {
  'purchase': {
    'actionField': {
    'id': {{Random Number}},                          // Transaction ID. Dummy
    'revenue': {{Revenue}},  // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
    'shipping': {{Shipping}}
    },
    'products': [
     for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      'name': a[i+1].innerHTML,
      'id': b[i].innerHTML,
      'quantity': c[i].innerHTML,
      'price': d[i].innerHTML  
     },
     ]
}
};
return ecommerceData;
}
```

If I use the code without the For loop, it works:

```
function() {
var a = document.querySelectorAll("p.product-name");
var b = document.querySelectorAll("small.cart_ref");
var c = document.querySelectorAll("input.cart_quantity_input.form-control.grey")
var d = document.querySelectorAll("li.price");
var e = c.value;
var ecommerceData = {
'ecommerce': {
  'purchase': {
    'actionField': {
    'id': {{Random Number}},                          // Transaction ID. Dummy
    'revenue': {{Revenue}},  // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
    'shipping': {{Shipping}}
    },
    'products': [
      {
      {'name': a[1].innerHTML,
      'id': b[0].innerHTML,
      'quantity': e[0].innerHTML,
      'price': d[0].innerHTML  
      }
     ]
 }
}
};
return ecommerceData;
}
```

The order transaction page is [www.decathlon.in/order](http://www.decathlon.in/order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert a loop in an object literal

Create the products array separately.

```
var products = [];
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = a[i+1].innerHTML;
    obj.id= b[i].innerHTML;
    obj.quantity= c[i].innerHTML;
    obj.price= d[i].innerHTML; 
    products.push(obj);
 }
```

Then add it to your object

```
'products': products
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

The syntax error is that you're trying to use a `for` statement where an *expression* is required (in an array initializer). Statements aren't expressions. (Expressions are sometimes statements, but not the other way around.)

The body of the `for` loop is also syntactically invalid. The body of a `for` loop should be a series of statements, but you've written a series of property initializers there as though they were inside an object initializer.

If you *did* execute your `for` loop, it would likely fail, because it's relying on three things that are probably not reliable:

1. That `a` will always have more elements in it than `b`, because you're doing `a[i + 1].innerHTML`. If `a` doesn't have more elements than `b`, eventually `a[i + 1]` will be `undefined` and you'll get an error trying to read `innerHTML` on `undefined`.
2. That `c` will always have at least as many elements in it as `b`; if it doesn't, eventually you'll try to read `innerHTML` on `undefined`.
3. That `d` will always have at least as many elements in it as `b`.

The reason your version without the `for` works is that you're not trying to use a statement as an expresion, and apparently `a` has at least two elements and `b`, `c`, and `d` all apparently have at least one element.

**If** your goal is to produce an array containing entries from those various elements, you could do it like this:

```
'products': Array.prototype.map.call(b, function(bvalue, i) {
    return {
        name:     a[i + 1] && a[i + 1].innerHTML,
        id:       bvalue,
        quantity: c[i] && c[i].innerHTML,
        price:    d[i] && d[i].innerHTML
    };
}),
```

*(I kept the `a[i + 1]` thing above on the theory it's really want you want to do...)*

That calls `Array#map` on `b` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for details); the result will be an array built from the values returned by the callback. The `c[i] && c[i].innerHTML` and similar will give you `undefined` if there is no `c[i]` element.

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J. That's a very detailed explanation and helped me understand where I was going wrong!